# html5lightbox not working after ajax load more

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a product page with so many images. I am using ajax load more to load extra product images. But html5lightbox is not working on the ajax load more products. Here is my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php if( $hasLoadMore ) { ?>

        $('#loadMore').click(function(event) {
            /* Act on the event */
            $button = $(this);
            $(this).prop("disabled",true);
            var offset = Number($('#offset').val());
            var limit = $('#limit').val();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax_walltiles.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {parent_category:'<?php echo $parentCateogry; ?>',product_limit:$("#product_limit").val(),offset: offset+1,limit:limit,order_field:$('#order_field').val(),order_by:$('#order_by').val(),parent_page_id:$("#parent_page_id").val()}
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                $button.prop("disabled",false);
                if( data != "empty" )
                {
                    $("#offset").val(offset+1);
                    $('#category_contents').append(data);
                    $('#Grid').mixitup({
                        effects: ['fade','scale','blur'],
                        transitionSpeed: 500
                    });
                    $(this).prop("disabled",false);
                }
                else
                {
                    $("#loadMore").hide();
                }
            });

        });

        $('#loadMore').click(function(){
            $('#category_contents').show();

        <?php } ?>
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to re-initiate the light box after each load-more response give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Try Using delegation method :

```
$(document).on('click', "#loadMore", function(event){
      // All your code here
});
```

Instead of simple click event which you have written.

This shall work for you..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.done(function (data) {
    $button.prop("disabled", false);
    if (data != "empty") {
        $("#offset").val(offset + 1);
        $('#category_contents').append(data);
        $('#Grid').mixitup({
            effects: ['fade', 'scale', 'blur'],
            transitionSpeed: 500
        });
        $(".html5lightbox").html5lightbox();//<-- initialize lightbox again
        $(this).prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
        $("#loadMore").hide();
    }
});
```