# html5 lightbox dose not work on ajax loaded <a> link

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to display data of text file in **HTML5 Lightbox**.

HTML5 Lightbox working fine when simply use it in any link of page.

**Example :**

```
<a data-height="500" data-width="800" href="hello.txt" class="html5lightbox">hello</a>
```

It's working in above link.
But when loading content in DataTables with ajax and click on the link in table then it's redirect to the hello.txt instants of displaying HTML5 Lightbox.

**[Update]**

```
$('.dynamicTable').on('xhr.dt', function ( e, settings, json ) {
            $(".html5lightbox").html5lightbox();
        }).dataTable();
```

It's not working on fired Ajax event when an Ajax request is completed.

Comment: Careful, html5lightbox is a jquery plugin: a lightbox coded with HTML5. It's not a HMTL5 problem. Have you seen that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25497859/html5lightbox-not-working-after-ajax-load-more ? ... It says you should call $(".html5lightbox").html5lightbox(); to initialize lightbox again

Comment: what is your exact problem?

Comment: @Nicolas it's still not working. And i know lightbox is a jQuery plug-in. But it's not work in loaded content...

Comment: @Amy Problem i describe in question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I get the answer of it :)

```
$('.dynamicTable').dataTable({
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {
        $(".html5lightbox").html5lightbox();          
    },
});
```

Make sour it's helps to other who working with [DataTable](http://datatables.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work surely

```
    jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
      jQuery(".html5lightbox").html5lightbox();
    });
```